# Поместить текст в Ace редактор

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, ace

Нашел `markdown` редактор на `js`, построенный на базе текстового редактора `Ace`[[GitHub](https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor)]. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается поместить текст в редактор уже после загрузки страницы(заранее - можно, просто указать в `textarea` нужный текст). Допустим есть шаблонный текст, который должен помещаться в редактор по нажатию на кнопку, но редактор создает свои теги и я не могу найти, где же хранится текст из редактора, чтобы туда добавить шаблоны. Может кто-то сталкивался с этим редактором и знает, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у кого-нибудь возникнет такая проблема, то вот решение:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editorID");
var customPosition = {
    row: 0,
    column: 0
};
var text = "This text has been dinamically inserted";
editor.session.insert(customPosition , text);
```

Если возникнет конкретно с `inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor`, то решение:

```
var editor = ace.edit($('#editorID').parent().find('.md-editor')[0]);
editor.setValue("Text", 1);
```